# Can't register my Google Apps Script Web app in Chrome Web store

Tags: google-apps-script, chrome-web-store

I've developed a Google Apps Script Web app called [VALET](https://script.google.com/d/1CwQEHJ-qbeRc743T-aIPlyBZpQFP7zaWmNjKQCioVZCr2MH2vTNPBwfw/edit) and would like to publish it in the Chrome Web Store. However, when I use the 'Publish'->'Register in Chrome Web Store' menu item in the GAS Script Editor I get the following message:

> Your project was not registered. Before you can register an item in the Chrome Web Store, you must accept the Terms of Service.

Note: I've paid the 5$ developer signup fee already but haven't published any item on the store yet.

So, I'm wondering, where can I accept the ToS or is this maybe a bug in the Script Editor?

Comment: Can you confirm that the Google account you're trying to publish the script from is the same one with which you paid the $5 developer registration fee? Also, if you go to https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard from that account, are you prompted to accept the ToS?

Comment: Thanks @JanKleinert for your help. Yes, in both cases it is 'michael.hausenblas@gmail.com' and no, if I visit the dashboard I am not prompted to accept the ToS (though I might have been a while ago when I signed up for it). Does this help?

Comment: Yes, that does help. One more question. Can you paste in the project key for your script? You can find it in the script editor under File > Project Properties. If you don't want to paste it here, you can email it to me at jkleinert AT google.com

Comment: @JanKleinert I've published the key directly on the app [1] (at the bottom), so no big secret really:) ... it's MLV5fFrjpUsoyWx5m7UEOG2Wefjxih5_4 - tx for your help!

[1] https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw2wbwXq2DKZqo1z3xnmj9DXjeN-ad1WRE7i-rQfKr3BVWHsuk/exec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've raised this in the issue tracker as http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1774. It looks like you have accepted the ToS and paid the registration fee, so I've raised this with the engineering team for them to look into why you're still getting an error. If you 'star' the issue, you'll get updates as they're added to the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for the speedy and focused help!